# Didn't add Class to Branchgroup

Tags: java

I'm create classes `DirectionalLight.java` and `Core.java`. The first I create awt DirectionalLight and `DirectionalLight.java` class' code is:

```
private Light DirectionalLight(){

    DirectionalLight directionalLight = new DirectionalLight(true, new Color3f(1.0f,
            1.0f, 1.0f), new Vector3f(-0.3f, 0.2f, -1.0f));

    directionalLight.setInfluencingBounds(new BoundingSphere(new Point3d(), 10000.0));

    return directionalLight;
}
```

The second I create branchgroup class and `Core.java` code:

```
BranchGroup branchGroup = new BranchGroup();

    viewTransform = universe.getViewingPlatform().getViewPlatformTransform();

    PlatformGeometry platformGeom = new PlatformGeometry();
    universe.getViewingPlatform().setPlatformGeometry(platformGeom);

    branchGroup.addChild(DirectionalLight());//this line generate problem
```

When I add DirectionalLight class to branchgroup compiler output: test cannot be resolved to a variable. How to improve this problem ? How to add another class to branchgroup ?

Comment: Please update your question with a
[minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).
For further information, please see [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask),
and take the [tour of the site](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Comment: maybe use  branchGroup.addChild(createLight());

Comment: it's don't work. Compiler tell that need Node group class

Comment: `test cannot be resolved to a variable` There is no `test` variable in the code you provided. We need the actual code.

Comment: But how to resolve this ? I used many methods but doesn't work

Comment: maybe try to understand what you are doing instead of copying code fragments together ....

Comment: I develop project on Eclipse using Java3D library and I need to add antoher class(directionallight) to branchgroup(Core.java)

Answer (score 0):

inspired by that tutorial i created a version similar to yours which is working: (http://www.java3d.org/lighting.html)

```
import javax.media.j3d.BoundingSphere;
import javax.media.j3d.BranchGroup;
import javax.media.j3d.DirectionalLight;
import javax.media.j3d.Light;
import javax.vecmath.Color3f;
import javax.vecmath.Point3d;
import javax.vecmath.Vector3f;

import com.sun.j3d.utils.geometry.Sphere;
import com.sun.j3d.utils.universe.SimpleUniverse;

public class Java3D {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.setProperty("sun.awt.noerasebackground", "true");
    new Java3D();
}

public Java3D() {
    final SimpleUniverse universe = new SimpleUniverse();
    final BranchGroup group = new BranchGroup();
    final Sphere sphere = new Sphere(0.5f);
    group.addChild(sphere);
    // here you add the created light
    group.addChild(createLight());

    universe.getViewingPlatform().setNominalViewingTransform();
    universe.addBranchGraph(group);

}

private Light createLight() {
    final DirectionalLight directionalLight = new DirectionalLight(true, new Color3f(1.0f,
            1.0f, 1.0f), new Vector3f(-0.3f, 0.2f, -1.0f));
    directionalLight.setInfluencingBounds(new BoundingSphere(new Point3d(), 100.0));
    return directionalLight;
}
}
```

Comment: I know I know. My project's main class like this. But I need take apart full code to different classes. In this situation i to apply stackoverflow

Comment: by why .. having a class DirectionalLight.java makes absolutely no sense, unless you extend the light in any way .. otherwise a factory method or class will do it

Comment: I need take apart code because I need manipulate lights, objects and etc. in another class which is controller(write with Swing library).

Answer (score 0):

Okay, but thats just simple java. Here the version with dedicated classes which are extracted.

```
import javax.media.j3d.BoundingSphere;
import javax.media.j3d.BranchGroup;
import javax.media.j3d.DirectionalLight;
import javax.vecmath.Color3f;
import javax.vecmath.Point3d;
import javax.vecmath.Vector3f;

import com.sun.j3d.utils.geometry.Sphere;
import com.sun.j3d.utils.universe.SimpleUniverse;

public class Java3D {

    private class MyDirectionalLight extends DirectionalLight {

        public MyDirectionalLight() {
            final Color3f color = new Color3f(1.8f, 0.8f, 0.1f);
            setColor(color);
            final Vector3f direction = new Vector3f(4.0f, -7.0f, -12.0f);
            setDirection(direction);
            setInfluencingBounds(new BoundingSphere(new Point3d(), 100.0));
        }

    }

    private class MySphere extends Sphere {
        public MySphere() {
            super(0.5f);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("sun.awt.noerasebackground", "true");
        new Java3D();
    }

    public Java3D() {
        final SimpleUniverse universe = new SimpleUniverse();
        final BranchGroup group = new BranchGroup();

        final MySphere mySphere = new MySphere();
        group.addChild(mySphere);

        final MyDirectionalLight myDirectionalLight = new MyDirectionalLight();
        group.addChild(myDirectionalLight);

        universe.getViewingPlatform().setNominalViewingTransform();
        universe.addBranchGraph(group);

    }

}
```

Comment: You have accounts in Whatsapp or Instagram or any social sites ?

Comment: It's not working dude. I try this but no result. When I launch this class it's working, But when I take appart and create contructor and add it to branchgoup compiler get error and says that this class must be node